# Running native windows applications on a smartphone

Tags: delphi, mobile, windows-8, windows-10, smartphone

I'm looking for a smartphone running Windows 10 that can execute native windows executables (build with Delphi, no universal Apps). Is this possible by design? Or aren't there such devices, since Windows 10 on smartphone isn't the same Windows 10 running on desktops?
At the end, I would also take native Windows 8.1 on smartphones - the main point is: to run native windows programs on it.

Is this possible?

Comment: There are Windows 10 tablets (Intel based) that run regular Windows 10 and regular Delphi windows applications run fine on them. I am not aware of any mobile phone that runs regular Windows 10, at the moment, but in theory if they would run it, Delphi apps would work on it.

Comment: You may use remote access to the desktop app. But not run the Windows apps directly on the smartphone.

Comment: Microsoft's "Project Centennial" bridge wraps a Win32 native app as a Universal Windows App so it can be submitted to the Windows Store. **IF** the app does not depend on elevated privileges, kernel access, etc, then it **might** run on a Windows 10 phone. See [This is how Win32 apps can become Windows Store apps](http://liliputing.com/2015/05/this-is-how-win32-apps-can-become-windows-store-apps.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

No this is not possible. Phones do not run Win32 executables.

Comment: Not directly but remoting solutions such as Citrix XenApp can deliver Windows applications to mobile devices.

Comment: @remko Of course, but I don't think that's what was asked

Comment: Yes that's why I added it as a comment as it might still be helpful for others